# function on Informix to replace characters doesn't work

Tags: sql, informix

I have been try to crete a function to get a value, replace a specific character and return it.

Data on table caracteres

```
caracter remplazo 
Ñ          N
ñ          n
á          a
é          e
Ê          E
```

Function

```
create function "informix".arreglar_cadenaAndSec(rt_nombre char(50))
    Returning char(50)
    Define fix_caracter char(3);
    Define fix_remplazo char(3);
    FOREACH SELECT caracter,remplazo
        INTO fix_caracter,fix_remplazo
        FROM caracteres     
        Let rt_nombre=replace(rt_nombre,fix_caracter,fix_remplazo);
    END FOREACH
    return rt_nombre;
End Function;
```

Input

```
FÊLIX
```

Output

```
FÊLIX
```

Desired  output

```
FELIX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the TRIM() function on the old_string and new_string arguments to the REPLACE() function as in this example:

```
create table characters(character char(3), replchar char(3));
insert into characters values("A", "a");
insert into characters values("C", "c");
insert into characters values("E", "e");

create function replchar(s1 char(50))
returning char(50);
define cin char(3);
define crepl char(3);
foreach select character, replchar into cin, crepl
from characters
  let s1 = replace(s1, trim(cin), trim(crepl));
end foreach
return s1;
end function;
  
execute function replchar("ABCDEF");
```

This gives the output:

```
aBcDeF
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to reproduce your problem.  I used this code to try and reproduce it:

```
select replace("platypus and wombat - archetypal critters", "y", "elephant") as answer from dual;
```

That yields: `platelephantpus and wombat - archetelephantpal critters`

```
select replace("platypus aÑd wombat - archetypal critters", "Ñ", "**N**") as answer from dual;
```

That yields: `platypus a**N**d wombat - archetypal critters`

Both of those simply test the `REPLACE` function, including on accented letters.

Then, trying your scenario:

```
create function "informix".arreglar_cadenaAndSec(rt_nombre char(50))
    Returning char(50)
    Define fix_caracter char(3);
    Define fix_remplazo char(3);
    FOREACH SELECT caracter,remplazo
        INTO fix_caracter,fix_remplazo
        FROM caracteres     
        Let rt_nombre=replace(rt_nombre,fix_caracter,fix_remplazo);
    END FOREACH
    return rt_nombre;
End Function;

create table caracteres(caracter varchar(5) not null, remplazo varchar(10) not null);

insert into caracteres values('Ñ', 'N');
insert into caracteres values('ñ', 'n');
insert into caracteres values('á', 'a');
insert into caracteres values('é', 'e');
insert into caracteres values('Ê', 'E');

execute function arregular_cadenaAndSec('Qua (Ñ N) (ñ n) (á a) (é e) (Ê E)');
```

The output from that is:

```
Qua (N  N) (n  n) (a  a) (e  e) (E  E)
```

That, I think, is what you'd want from the given the entries in the `caracteres` table.

I'm testing with IDS 14.10.FC1DE on RHEL 7.4.
My environment is:

```
DBDATE=Y4MD-
DBEDIT=vim
INFORMIXCONCSMCFG=/work1/informix/jl-ibm-14.10.FC1/etc/concsm.njdc_ldev04_23
INFORMIXDIR=/work1/informix/jl-ibm-14.10.FC1
INFORMIXSERVER=njdc_ldev04_23
INFORMIXTERM=terminfo
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64:/usr/lib64:/usr/gcc/v12.2.0/lib64:/usr/gcc/v12.2.0/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/work1/informix/jl-ibm-14.10.FC1/lib:/work1/informix/jl-ibm-14.10.FC1/lib/esql:/work1/informix/jl-ibm-14.10.FC1/lib/cli
ONCONFIG=onconfig.njdc_ldev04_23
PATH=.:/work2/jleffler/bin:/u/jleffler/bin:/work1/informix/jl-ibm-14.10.FC1/bin:/atria_release/cmbin:/atria_release/cmbin/mergescripts:/atria_release/cm_dist/vobs/imitools/bin:/usr/atria/bin:/u/jleffler/aux/njdc-ldev04:/usr/perl/v5.34.0/bin:/usr/gcc/v12.2.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/rational/clearcase/bin
SQLCMDLOG=/work2/jleffler/.sqlcmdlog
SQLEXEC=sqlrm
TERM=xterm-256color
TERMINFO=/u/jleffler/terminfo
```